# Can I use OpenStack Rocky with a neoverse-n1?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openstack, qemu, openstack-nova, arm

**Situation**: For now, I'm stuck on OpenStack Rocky on Ubuntu 18.04.6 and I have some beefy Neoverse-n1 hardware (aarch64, 64-core, 1TB memory) to integrate. **Can I accomplish this with on my current OS cluster, or is this futile?**

```
# qemu-system-aarch64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.11.1(Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.41)
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
# virsh --version
4.0.0
# uname -r
5.4.0-137-generic
```

**How Far I've gotten:** I can create a VM from the command line like this:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -cpu host  -machine virt,accel=kvm,gic-version=3  -m 8G -smp 4 ...
```

**Problem:**

I am struggling to integrating this with OpenStack Rocky.  I think the defaults for OpenStack/libvirt/qemu versions didn't account for this sort of hardware, so I'm expecting to do a lot of overrides.  I'm getting libvirt or qemu validation errors like:

```
libvirtError: XML error: memballoon unsupported with address type 'none'
qemu-system-aarch64: Unsupported NIC model: virtio-net
qemu-system-aarch64: Unsupported NIC model: lan9118
```

My current nova.conf contains:

```
[libvirt]
  virt_type = kvm
  cpu_mode = host-passthrough
  hw_machine_type = virt,accel=kvm,gic-version=3
```

**More hardware info:**

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=max -device \? |& grep virtio :
…
name "virtio-balloon-device", bus virtio-bus
name "virtio-balloon-pci", bus PCI, alias "virtio-balloon"
…
name "virtio-net-device", bus virtio-bus
name "virtio-net-pci", bus PCI, alias "virtio-net"

lspci:
    …
    0001:01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
    0001:01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
    …
    0003:02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    0003:02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is a really ugly long line, but this works for me:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 -name guest=ol9-aarch64,debug-threads=on -S -object {"qom-type":"secret","id":"masterKey0","format":"raw","file":"/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-58-ol9-aarch64/master-key.aes"} -blockdev {"driver":"file","filename":"/usr/share/edk2/aarch64/QEMU_EFI-silent-pflash.raw","node-name":"libvirt-pflash0-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"} -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-pflash0-format","read-only":true,"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-pflash0-storage"} -blockdev {"driver":"file","filename":"/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/ol9-aarch64_VARS.fd","node-name":"libvirt-pflash1-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"} -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-pflash1-format","read-only":false,"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-pflash1-storage"} -machine virt-7.2,usb=off,gic-version=2,dump-guest-core=off,memory-backend=mach-virt.ram,pflash0=libvirt-pflash0-format,pflash1=libvirt-pflash1-format -accel tcg -cpu neoverse-n1 -m 4096 -object {"qom-type":"memory-backend-ram","id":"mach-virt.ram","size":4294967296} -overcommit mem-lock=off -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid bfe5ded2-a972-4464-a135-9c1dca08e155 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=81,server=on,wait=off -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -boot strict=on -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":8,"chassis":1,"id":"pci.1","bus":"pcie.0","multifunction":true,"addr":"0x1"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":9,"chassis":2,"id":"pci.2","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1.0x1"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":10,"chassis":3,"id":"pci.3","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1.0x2"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":11,"chassis":4,"id":"pci.4","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1.0x3"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":12,"chassis":5,"id":"pci.5","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1.0x4"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":13,"chassis":6,"id":"pci.6","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1.0x5"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":14,"chassis":7,"id":"pci.7","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1.0x6"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":15,"chassis":8,"id":"pci.8","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1.0x7"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":16,"chassis":9,"id":"pci.9","bus":"pcie.0","multifunction":true,"addr":"0x2"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":17,"chassis":10,"id":"pci.10","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x1"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":18,"chassis":11,"id":"pci.11","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x2"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":19,"chassis":12,"id":"pci.12","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x3"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":20,"chassis":13,"id":"pci.13","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x4"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":21,"chassis":14,"id":"pci.14","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x5"} -device {"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":22,"chassis":15,"id":"pci.15","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x6"} -device {"driver":"pcie-pci-bridge","id":"pci.16","bus":"pci.7","addr":"0x0"} -device {"driver":"qemu-xhci","p2":15,"p3":15,"id":"usb","bus":"pci.2","addr":"0x0"} -device {"driver":"virtio-scsi-pci","id":"scsi0","bus":"pci.3","addr":"0x0"} -device {"driver":"virtio-serial-pci","id":"virtio-serial0","bus":"pci.4","addr":"0x0"} -blockdev {"driver":"file","filename":"/var/lib/zhive/shared/isos/OracleLinux-R8-U6-aarch64-dvd.iso","node-name":"libvirt-2-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"} -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":true,"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-2-storage"} -device {"driver":"scsi-cd","bus":"scsi0.0","channel":0,"scsi-id":0,"lun":0,"device_id":"drive-scsi0-0-0-0","drive":"libvirt-2-format","id":"scsi0-0-0-0","bootindex":1} -blockdev {"driver":"host_device","filename":"/dev/vg0/mydisk","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-1-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"} -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-1-format","read-only":false,"discard":"unmap","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-1-storage"} -device {"driver":"scsi-hd","bus":"scsi0.0","channel":0,"scsi-id":0,"lun":1,"device_id":"drive-scsi0-0-0-1","drive":"libvirt-1-format","id":"scsi0-0-0-1","write-cache":"on"} -netdev {"type":"tap","fd":"82","id":"hostnet0"} -device {"driver":"virtio-net-pci","netdev":"hostnet0","id":"net0","mac":"52:54:00:52:6b:1a","bus":"pci.1","addr":"0x0"} -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -serial chardev:charserial0 -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,fd=73,server=on,wait=off -device {"driver":"virtserialport","bus":"virtio-serial0.0","nr":1,"chardev":"charchannel0","id":"channel0","name":"org.qemu.guest_agent.0"} -chardev socket,id=chrtpm,path=/run/libvirt/qemu/swtpm/58-ol9-aarch64-swtpm.sock -tpmdev emulator,id=tpm-tpm0,chardev=chrtpm -device {"driver":"tpm-tis-device","tpmdev":"tpm-tpm0","id":"tpm0"} -device {"driver":"usb-tablet","id":"input0","bus":"usb.0","port":"1"} -audiodev {"id":"audio1","driver":"none"} -vnc 127.0.0.1:19,audiodev=audio1 -device {"driver":"VGA","id":"video0","vgamem_mb":16,"bus":"pci.16","addr":"0x1"} -device {"driver":"virtio-balloon-pci","id":"balloon0","bus":"pci.5","addr":"0x0"} -object {"qom-type":"rng-random","id":"objrng0","filename":"/dev/urandom"} -device {"driver":"virtio-rng-pci","rng":"objrng0","id":"rng0","bus":"pci.6","addr":"0x0"} -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
```

and this is the libvirt xml that generated it:

```xml
<domain type='qemu'>
  <name>ol9-aarch64</name>
  <uuid>bfe5ded2-a972-4464-a135-9c1dca08e155</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://oracle.com/ol/9"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <os firmware='efi'>
    <type arch='aarch64' machine='virt-7.2'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <gic version='2'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='none'>
    <model fallback='allow'>neoverse-n1</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/zhive/shared/isos/OracleLinux-R8-U6-aarch64-dvd.iso'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
      <source dev='/dev/vg0/mydisk'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='scsi'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x8'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x9'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0xa'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0xb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0xc'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0xd'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0xe'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='8' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='8' port='0xf'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='9' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='9' port='0x10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='10' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='10' port='0x11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='11' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='11' port='0x12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='12' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='12' port='0x13'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='13' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='13' port='0x14'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='14' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='14' port='0x15'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='15' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='15' port='0x16'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='16' model='pcie-to-pci-bridge'>
      <model name='pcie-pci-bridge'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x07' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:52:6b:1a'/>
      <source bridge='vlanbr88'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target type='system-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='pl011'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </input>
    <tpm model='tpm-tis'>
      <backend type='emulator' version='2.0'/>
    </tpm>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address'/>
    </graphics>
    <audio id='1' type='none'/>
    <video>
      <model type='vga' vram='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x10' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model='virtio'>
      <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
</domain>
```